# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, maven

I am developing a WAR project in Eclipse Mars which is running on a Tomcat 7 application server. I am also using the Java JSON API to create JSONObjects from a REST web service.I have ensured that my `pom.xml` file includes the JSON dependency so that the correct jar is downloaded.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The jar can be seen in my project structure under

`Java Resources > Libraries > Maven Dependencies > json-20151123.jar`.

However, when I run my code on the server I receive the following exception.

```
    Feb 03, 2016 10:25:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/JsonHotUkDealsApi] threw exception [org/json/JSONObject] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.getPropertyDescriptor(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:386)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bakeBeanProperty(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:317)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:260)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:559)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does that json jar contain the class in question? Is the jar present in your application's lib folder/classpath (Maven dependencies are a hint but not the answer)?

Comment: Yes, the jar has the JSONObject class inside of it. My WebContent > WEB-INF > lib folder is empty.

Comment: tomcat will pick up jars from the lib folder only. If it doesn't find the jar, then definitely it wil throw an exception.

Comment: @Anshul, Maven will during WAR build auto-fill `/WEB-INF/lib` based on `<dependency>` entries declared in `pom.xml`.

Comment: Liam, apparently the build/deploy is still dirty. Make sure you clean/rebuild everything. Otherwise let Maven produce a WAR file which you then inspect with a ZIP tool (JSON library must be in `/WEB-INF/lib` in there)

Comment: Hi, I have used the maven war plugin and in deployment assembly settings of my project I have selected to include maven dependencies in my WEB-INF/ lib folder. All is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `gradle` and `eclipse` I worked around this problem by explicitly specifying the directory of the referenced libraries in the run command `java -cp build/libs/jarFile.jar:build/libs/* projectName.mainClassName` this is assuming the referenced `.jar` files are in `build/libs/*`

Answer (score -3):

You can use jackson mapper for change object to json.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
```

Comment: I have no problem converting my object to a JSONObject. My issue is that when run on the tomcat web server, the servlet does not pick up the jar despite it being in my maven pom.xml file.

Comment: first of all if you use eclipse IDE then press Alt + f5 and check on force update and apply that. 

then you need to create war then apply 
Steps: right click on your project on left side then select Run as -> maven install so that after process finish then find the war file in target folder of your project.

copy war file and paste into your tomcat server (c:/apache7.0/webapps) then go to c://apache/bin -> open startup.exe and check it on your browser like (locahost:8080/(war_file_name).